# How to return value in a function with a single line in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6

This works:

```
var power = (x)=>x*x
```

This works as well: (this returns an object with a qty:1 property)

```
let addQty = (payload)=>{payload.qty=1;return payload}
```

But this doesn't:

```
let addQty2 = (payload)=>{return payload.qty=1}
```

It instead returns 1.
Why?

ps: I know I can return the value after the statement like this:

`let addQty2 = (payload)=>{payload.qty=1;return payload;}`

,but I still can't understand why the previous one doesn't work.

Comment: In the second example, you are returning `payload`, in the third, you are returning `payload.qty`, which you have set to 1.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/bgxpatgs/. This returns `payload`.

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb doesn't that return an exact {qty:1}? What I want is basically this https://jsfiddle.net/bgxpatgs/1/, but by directly returning the value while mutating the object (if that is even possible)

Comment: Why don't you want to do option 2? It's very clear what you're trying to do and not too verbose.

Comment: @jhpratt I am sorry I didn't make myself clearer in the OP. I'm learning functional programming and should have used Object.assign to retain immutability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code works, but realize that you are changing the original object and then returning it.

```js
let addQty = payload=>{payload.qty=1; return payload;}

var obj = {
  name: "Some thing",
  price: 9.95
}

var newObj = addQty(obj);

console.log('obj', obj);
console.log('newObj', newObj);
```

This version:

```
let addQty2 = (payload)=>{return payload.qty=1}
```

Will return the last value used and not the object because the object is not the last value. the number `1` is the last value used.

If you want to only affect a new object then try this:

```js
let addQty = payload=>Object.assign({}, payload, {qty:1});

var obj = {
  name: "Some thing",
  price: 9.95
}

var newObj = addQty(obj);

console.log('obj', obj);
console.log('newObj', newObj);
```

This function returns the value that is returned from `Object.assign` which is the new object.

Comment: Yes, I considered using Object.assign, but thought it was too verbose or I was missing somehting obvious. I am actually learning functional programming with JS, and Object.assign does indeed seem to be the way to do it while respecting immutability.

Answer (score 4):

An assignment in JavaScript returns the assigned value. For example,

```
a = b = 1;
```

is parsed as

```
a = (b = 1);
```

The value of the expression of `b = 1` is `1`, so we assign that to `a`. Likewise, the return in your second example is parsed as

```
return (payload.qty = 1)
```

The value of the expression `payload.qty = 1` is `1`, so that is what is returned.